# Isomorphism between vector spaces of linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $V,W$ vector spaces over the field $F$,and let $U: V\rightarrow W$
>   an isomorphism between them.
>
> Prove that the linear transformation
>   $\mathcal{U}:\mathcal{L}(V,V)\rightarrow \mathcal{L}(W,W)$ defined by
>   $\mathcal{U}(T)=UTU^{-1}$ is an isomorphism between $\mathcal{L}(V,V)$
>   and $\mathcal{L}(W,W)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show that it is linear, i.e., that $U(\alpha T+\beta T')U^{-1}=\alpha UTU^{-1}+\beta UT'U^{-1}$; and exhibit the inverse $\mathcal L(W,W)\to \mathcal L(V,V)$ (it looks similar to $\mathcal U$).